# issues transforming string to date vega lite

Tags: vega-lite

I am trying to display some data in a line graph. However, my "Harvest_Year" data, which is a date in years, like 2017 or 2018, is being displayed as what I believe is a string

I imported by data from a .csv file, and the following are the steps I took to change the string to a date formate. I tired to do:

```
"Harvest_Year": "year"
```

But that did not work as it made all my values null. So I thought first I will make it into a int and then transform it into year. However in Vega-Lite all my years re displayed correctly in the table but when I display it on the line graph I only see 1970 which I am sure I don't have in the dataset, and it only displays that single year.

[image: line graph displaying only one year]

Where as in the image below, you can see I have all the years in my data:

[image: correct data]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DanStein91/Info-vis/master/CoffeeRobN.csv",
    "format": {
      "type": "csv",
            "parse": {
       "Number_of_Bags": "number",
        "Bag_weight": "number",
        "Harvest_Year": "number"
      }
    }
  },
  "transform": [
{
    "timeUnit": "year",
    "field": "Harvest_Year",
    "as": "Year"
  },
     {
      "calculate": "datum.Number_of_Bags * datum.Bag_Weight ",
      "as": "Total_Export"
    }
  ],  
      "width": 300,
      "height": 200,
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    
    "y": {
      "field": "Total_Export",
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
    "x": {
      "field": "Harvest_Year",
      "type": "temporal"
    }
  },
  "config": {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you tell vega-lite to interpret numbers as dates, it treats them as unix timestamps, i.e. milliseconds after January 1 1970. Each of your resulting dates is in the year 1970, which leads to the chart you are seeing.

Your dates appear to be in a non-standard format (e.g. `"2017.0"` means the year 2017) so you'll have to use [vega expressions](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/) to manually parse them into date objects. Here is an example of this ([view in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4yghSBXATgGxSgAt54AHAZ2QHpqdYB3AOgHMBLeIrAIywoFMcAYwD2AO3j8JTUQFtqAEVhiAypLZiAnAEZqASTEAzEQFoAbmwrVZsCpJzUAwiMOH+-AEojuAORkUzSAAacAxIYxwbeEJ0DEx4AE8yfkJIIQDg0LjIMlgcARisuKgfLFluQQB9F0qAIVgWClSxMoqcTOKw+pZKhn42FhJm1sEOzqgACTyzfjtKgE1+POHy0aKIAF8irc2Q+PoxCgjZQgBtIuBwtjx7VMsANVg8NmgACjh4MqYpnBm5xbyAEpIBs9hhLkInkIsHgEClUDA4fA2LJ+O8EF8fn94AsljggmBtMCCZBbKksbMcQD2qCLusoJC8NDYZJUh8vqVVjhqoY6g0KGAAFRgdmyJjdSoAdX6g3gUDB2TJCIAKiJEHhKgBRAAeZBEOGi21CAF0wZAbDgANapPUaaJmqSiaAaFiFbIJGJXfh4aCpVXqrW6-X2qCJZKpACOWGUyMQyJmIIVUG1nsMbG9voRFP+eOCoaS8Kg+udYieecgyNRAFUxBxUglczswLTMAwXpxCABmAAM3bNRBlQ1QACZeyANkA)):

```
{
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DanStein91/Info-vis/master/CoffeeRobN.csv",
    "format": {
      "type": "csv",
      "parse": {
        "Number_of_Bags": "number",
        "Bag_weight": "number",
        "Harvest_Year": "number"
      }
    }
  },
  "transform": [
    {"filter": "isValid(datum.Harvest_Year)"},
    {"calculate": "datetime(datum.Harvest_Year, 1)", "as": "Harvest_Year"},
    {
      "calculate": "datum.Number_of_Bags * datum.Bag_Weight ",
      "as": "Total_Export"
    }
  ],
  "mark": "point",
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "Total_Export", "type": "quantitative"},
    "x": {"field": "Harvest_Year", "type": "ordinal", "timeUnit": "year"}
  },
  "width": 300,
  "height": 200
}
```

[image]

Another option is to avoid `datetime` and `timeUnit` logic altogether (since your data does not actually contain any dates), and just use the year numbers directly in your encoding; e.g.

```
{
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DanStein91/Info-vis/master/CoffeeRobN.csv",
    "format": {
      "type": "csv",
      "parse": {
        "Number_of_Bags": "number",
        "Bag_weight": "number",
        "Harvest_Year": "number"
      }
    }
  },
  "transform": [
    {"filter": "isValid(datum.Harvest_Year)"},
    {
      "calculate": "datum.Number_of_Bags * datum.Bag_Weight ",
      "as": "Total_Export"
    }
  ],
  "mark": "point",
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "Total_Export", "type": "quantitative"},
    "x": {"field": "Harvest_Year", "type": "ordinal"}
  },
  "width": 300,
  "height": 200
}
```